# La lettre H dans les mots d'origine anglaise (e.g. noms propres commençant par H)

Tags: prononciation, h-aspiré

Comment faut-il prononcer des noms propres anglais qui commencent par la lettre H ? Par exemple

> La loi de Hooke ou d'Hooke.

Le prononce-t-on avec un h aspiré ou un h muet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Règle générale, la prononciation varie beaucoup en fonction de la maîtrise ou non de ce son par le locuteur. Si le son est prononcé, il y a une chance que des gens peu habitués à l’anglais *(ce genre de gens existera-t-il encore dans vingt ans, cependant ?)* ne le remarquent même pas. À plus forte raison, son absence ne sera jamais considérée comme fautive.

---

Au Canada, les gens prononceront souvent naturellement quelques sons anglais étrangers à la langue française dans les noms propres anglophones ou dans les mots empruntés (des emprunts qui font rarement l’unanimité, mais qui surviennent malgré tout), dont :

- le I court [ɪ] (qui est un allophone courant du i français au Canada) ;
- le R tel que prononcé en anglais canadien [ɹ], principalement dans les noms propres, parfois aussi, bien plus rarement, dans les emprunts ;
- le OO [uː] et le EE [iː], bien allongés en canadien français ([kul] pour *cool* ou [bit] pour *beat* y seraient perçus comme des facéties).

Ces quatre sons sont si communément utilisés qu’ils sont rapidement acquis par les très jeunes et font partie intégrante des sons qu’ils peuvent insérer sans même y réfléchir dans leur discours français.

Par contre, le H anglais, fortement aspiré, demande une certaine maîtrise de la langue anglaise, que tous ne possèdent pas forcément. Il est parfois utilisé par ceux qui la possède, mais pas toujours non plus.

Le L anglais, un peu plus tendu que celui du français, n’est à peu près jamais rendu, même par les gens maîtrisant bien l’anglais. La proximité assez grande des deux sons rend superflue la prononciation à l’anglaise.

---

Quant à la France, je ne suis guère qualifié pour en décrire les usages, mais je pourrai du moins utiliser l’information fournie ci-dessous par [aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526), qui indique que la prononciation des H anglais durant ses années d’école était à ce point ignorée et sans importance qu’ils pouvaient très bien même être traités comme des H muets. Ainsi, la loi de Hooke invoquée dans la question était alors, à l’oral du moins je suppose, **la loi d’Hooke**.

Comme référence à ce qu’est devenue cette habitude de nos jours, on pourrait par exemple penser à interroger les gens par rapport à Harry Potter : les livres **de** Harry Potter ou les livres **d’**Harry Potter ?

<sub>Ce genre de question aurait l’avantage de cibler une vision peut-être plus personnelle ou familiale, et donc variable, de la perception française du H anglais, qu’un terme spécialisé comme la loi de Hooke, que les étudiants ne connaissent probablement en majorité que depuis peu, et tous des mêmes quelques sources.</sub>

Et puisque l’OP travaille dans une université et qu’il côtoie beaucoup plus de gens que moi, je lui proposerai de mener cette petite enquête de son côté. Enquête dont je serais par ailleurs curieux de connaître le résultat...

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la prononciation du *H*, la façon que L'OP a choisi d'utiliser dans son exemple (d**E** Hooke), je veux dire et non d'Hook, serait elle aussi éloquente quant au choix à faire. Je le dis d'autant plus facilement que... étudiants nous ne connaissions que... *laloidouk*... ;-)

Comment: Je crois même être en mesure de généraliser mon comm ci-dessus : Bien que germanistes (et donc connaissant la prononciation du H allemand, on ne parlait que du *principdaillsenberg* et jamais du *principe de Heinsenberg*, de la *pressiondertz* et d'inductances de *deuzoutroizenry*... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Les noms courants d'après le wiktionnaire ne sont pas prononcés avec un h anglais lorsque on leur connait une prononciation ; ils ne semblent pas nombreux à avoir une prononciation bien établie. Les mots suivants ont une prononciation connue;

> Hendrix \ɛn.dʁiks\, Halloween \a.lɔ.win\, 
>   Hollywood (h aspiré)\ɔ.li.wud

La plupart des noms anglais n'ont pas de prononciation établie, toujours d'après le Wiktionnaire.

> \Prononciation ?\ Hook, Hall, Halley, Hamilton, Hayette, Hereford, Hepworth, Herford
>   Heriot, Heysham, Heywood, Hindley

D'après les habitudes générales de prononciation des français il ne faut pas prononcer de h anglais, c'est à dire un h avec une expiration. Cependant, dans certains mots comme « Hollywood » un h aspiré peut être la norme.

Comment: Merci ! Je comprends. Tu dis : "D'après les habitudes générales de prononciation des français il ne doit pas falloir prononcer de h anglais, c'est à dire un h avec une expiration." Mais comme ça les étudiants (physique, maths, ingénierie and the like:-)!) n'obtiendront jamais l'aise avec la prononciation anglaise.

Comment: @dimitris Je ne dis pas exactement qu'il ne faut absolument pas, je veux seulement dire que la grande majorité ne prononcent pas ce h à l'anglaise et que si quelqu'un ne le prononce pas personne ne pourra faire la remarque qu'il/elle enfreint une règle ; je veux dire aussi que la prononciation de ces h pourra peut être déplaire ; personnellement, ça ne me dérangerais pas et je pourrais faire l'effort de le prononcer bien que je n'aime pas mélanger des sons anglais avec des son français ; néanmoins si le h est prononcé il serait préférable que le mot entier soit prononcé à l'anglaise.