# Pronunciation of "Module de Young" versus "module d'Young": Explication and difference

Tags: anglais, prononciation, orthographe

I understand that a native can say

> Loi d'Hooke or de Hooke

depending on the level of mastery of English or/and his or her interpretation of the letter H as muet or aspiré. (In fact I posted a related question some time ago: [La lettre H dans les mots d'origine anglaise (e.g. noms propres commençant par H)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/la-lettre-h-dans-les-mots-dorigine-anglaise-e-g-noms-propres-commen%c3%a7ant-par-h))

What I cannot understand is how we can find the variation *module d'Young* when, actually, *module de Young* sounds (at least for me) more natural (à la yogurt ou yaourt).
How can one justify the former spelling? And how exactly is this (i.e. module d'Young) pronounced ?

Comment: toto is right for the correct pronounciation, but I tend to pronounce 'de' less to pronounce young, and I guess it's the fact I try to tell the word Young in a bad english, and the 'de' seem to get shortened for the 'ou' in young, [w], that is more present.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Merci. D'accord pour module de Young.  C'est comme ça que j'ai écris personnellement. Cependant, il existe pas mal de ressources francophones qui adopte l'écriture (spelling) module d'Young. Ma question est double : pourquoi ce choix ? et comment le prononce-t-on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [Dictionnaire de l'académie - Y](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8Y0001)

> Au début de la plupart des mots, il se comporte comme s’il était précédé d’une h aspirée, et la voyelle finale de l’article ou de la préposition de ne s’élide pas devant lui. Le yack. Le yucca. La yole. La pointe du yatagan. Une sorte de yacht. Toutefois, dans yeuse et ypérite, la voyelle finale de l’article ou de la préposition de s’élide. L’ypérite. Une feuille d’yeuse.

So, *a priori*, one should say: *“module de Young”* as well as *“Fentes de Young”*

Comment: Merci. Et comment alors se prononce-t-il ? Module d'Ioung ? Si tu cherche sur Internet, il y a pas mal de ressources qui adopte l'écriture modèle d'Young. Je ne comprends pas comment on peut explique ce choix.

Comment: Si tu cherche**s**; sorry:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris: Personnellement, j'applique la règle de l'Académie et je dis : « Module de *H*Young ». Cependant, « Young » étant un nom propre, il est possible que chacun choisisse sa prononciation et considère le *Y* comme un *I* simple.

Comment: Une bizarrerie (ou exception qui confirme la règle...): le *jambon d'York* - prononcé [djɔʁk].

Answer (score 3):

L'élision était plus fréquente jusqu'à la fin du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Depuis, son absence a légèrement pris le dessus.

Tu as donc le choix :

[image]

[image]